# SURF feature input to neural network in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, computer-vision, neural-network, matlab-cvst

Can I input the SURF feature obtained by the MATLAB command (detectSURFFeature) as input to the neural network to train network in order to classify/detect the object in the image?.if yes how can I cop with the multidimensional data obtained by the descriptor? I am using image set of same resolution and almost similar orientation. I am using only MATLAB.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to use the [bag of features](http://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/examples/image-category-classification-using-bag-of-features.html) approach. You discretize the space of the SURF descriptors, and then you compute a histogram of the descriptors in your image. This gives you a single vector that you can use at input to a neural network or any other classifier of your choice.

Comment: Ok good. any way my MATLAB tool box doesn't contain the bag of features is there any implemented code (in MATLAB) for that if yes please help me to find out that. Thanks in advance.